# Messages in a Queue based on order

Tags: message-queue, iot

What is the best way to make sure you have all the messages in the proper order in your queue such as SQS or Kafka?

Basically, I need to make sure all the messages that I have in the queue are ordered for example based on date+time and process them online.  I need to do this because I need to process only the first 1000 messages in the queue online. What is the best approach here?

Comment: what do you mean by proper order? how are you sending that information and how do you expect to process it?

Comment: here is the scenario - you are designing a webpage for a global online retail and there is promotion for customers.  The promotion is the first 1000 customers who sign up for a specific program get $100 credit for shopping.  This credit MUST be online and available once the customer sign up for the promotion.  Now the question is how do you make sure the order of your messages in the queue (any queue - can be kafka, SQS, etc.) to make sure that you are processing the first 1000 customers only in the right order?